# Java 11 Class Data Sharing Memory

Tags: java, jvm

I am trying to configure a number of Java microservices to use the [class data sharing](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/vm/class-data-sharing.html#GUID-7EAA3411-8CF0-4D19-BD05-DF5E1780AA91) feature in Java 11 openjdk in order to reduce the memory footprint of the application. My basic process has been as follows:

1. Move any JAR that occurs in atleast a certain number of my microservices from the microservices lib folder into a single "shared lib" directory on my machine.
2. Run a dummy program that calls class.forName() on every class in the shared lib with the -Xshare:dump option
3. Run the [cl4cds tool](https://github.com/simonis/cl4cds) on the output to parse the previous output into the necessary format
4. Run another dummy java program to load each class and create the shared archive
5. Start each microservice with -Xshare:on and a classpath that starts with the shared lib followed by the jars still remaining in the microservice's lib folder.

When I start up the microservices I output the class loading to a log file using -Xlog:class+load=info:file=/loaded-from.txt. Reading this file I can see that roughly 66% of my classes are being loaded via "shared object", but I am not seeing any memory reduction via the top command or /proc/pid/smaps.

Is there a reason I shouldnt be seeing a memory reduction considering I am able to share roughly 66% of the classes across each of my 80-ish services?

Comment: You are starting 80 different JVMs? --- Which value in `top` command would you expect to go down, and why would you expect that?

Comment: I expected to see the used memory reported by top to go down. I expected this to go down because the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/tools/java.html#GUID-31503FCE-93D0-4175-9B4F-F6A738B2F4C4) say: "You can share the same archive file across multiple applications processes. This reduces memory usage because the archive is memory-mapped into the address space of the processes. The operating system automatically shares the read-only pages across these processes."

Comment: What is the size of resulting CDS archive? This will be the upper limit of theoretically possible saving. In practice, the footprint reduction is far less than that - maybe, a few megabytes per instance - not something that can be easily noticed in `top`. Check [NativeMemoryTracking](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/vm/nmt-8.html) to be sure.

Comment: The archive size is 257 Mb, obviously I dont expect to see the that amount of savings across each of the 80 services, but there are enough re-used jars across enough services that I do expect to see a chunk of savings overall.

Comment: My major confusion at the moment is I am able to see that the classes are being pulled from the shared location, so I know that it is working. But I am not able to see that in the memory usage via top. It seems that could be caused by 2 reasons to me: 1, the memory is shared in such a way that it looks to top like it is using more memory than it actually is, or 2 that there is something about my configuration where it is being pulled from the shared location but the shared location itself is being copied in each service and is not actually being shared

Comment: As a followup, changing the garbage collector seems to have an inordinate effect on this. The doc states that the application data sharing works with the G1 and parallel garbage collectors. With the default G1 collector at Java 11 running with CDS leads to an increase in memory of about 4 gb, changing to run with the parallel GC leads to a decrease of 4 gb from the base measurement (a swing of 8 gb by changing GCs). I dont know why this is having such a dramatic effect, but I'll leave this here in case anyone has any ideas or runs into a similar problem